# How to schedule a task with wix?

Tags: wix, windows-xp

I am trying to schedule a task with wix installer.Installer is installed successfully but the task is not added to task scheduler.I am using windows xp.

```
<Product Id="*" 
  Name="FooBar" 
  Language="1033" 
  Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Foo" 
  UpgradeCode="GID">
<Package Id="*" 
  InstallerVersion="200" 
  Compressed="yes" 
  InstallScope="perMachine" 
  InstallPrivileges="elevated"/>
        ...        
</Product>

<Fragment>
  <CustomAction Id="CreateScheduledTask" 
    Return="check" 
    Impersonate="no" 
    Execute="deferred"
    Directory="TARGETDIR" 
    ExeCommand=""[SystemFolder]SCHTASKS.EXE" /CREATE /SC MINUTE /MO 20 /TN "Foobar"  /TR "[INSTALLFOLDER]\Foobar.exe" /RU "NT Authority\System" /RP" />
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Word of warning if you ship to non-english speaking countries, the command line options to schtasks are not always the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't include when your CustomAction takes place in the Install Sequence.  If it should be after the installation or upon close.

```
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action='CreateScheduledTask' After='InstallFiles'/>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Also, nesting quotes never works for me.  I use `&quot;` inside any quotes.  Here's an example creating a service.

```
<CustomAction Id="MyService" 
              Property="CMD" 
              ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /c sc create &quot;MyService&quot;  binPath= &quot;[#MyService.exe]&quot; start= auto  type= interact type= own" 
              Execute="deferred" 
              Return="check" 
              Impersonate="no"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what ended up working for me (Adapted from http://kamivaniea.com/?p=632):

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CreateScheduledTask" After="InstallFiles">
    NOT Installed
  </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomAction Id="CreateScheduledTask"
    Return="check"
    Impersonate="no"
    Execute="deferred"
    Directory="TARGETDIR"
    ExeCommand="&quot;[SystemFolder]SCHTASKS.EXE&quot; /Create /TN &quot;Task Name Here&quot; /TR &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]MyExecutable.exe&quot; /SC WEEKLY /D MON /ST 05:00 /F" />
```

When I did what Val suggested I'd get this error in the logs (`msiexec /l*v log.txt /i MyInstaller.msi`):

> Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

This is what I had:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='CreateScheduledTask' After='InstallFiles'/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<CustomAction Id="CreateScheduledTask"
  Property="CMD"
  ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /c schtasks /Create /TN &quot;Task Name Here&quot; /TR &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]MyExecutable.exe&quot; /SC WEEKLY /D MON /ST 05:00 /F"
  Execute="deferred"
  Return="check"
  Impersonate="no"/>
```